# Not Understanding Pointer Arithmetic with ++ and --

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

So, I am learning about pointers via http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ and I do not understand anything about the pointer arithmetic section. Could someone clear things up or point me to a tutorial about this that I may better understand.

I am especially confused with all the parentheses things like the difference between `*p++`,`(*p)++`, `*(p++)`, and etc.

Comment: You should look into [order of operations](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+order+of+operations) and/or [operator precedence](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+operator+precedence) in C++.

Comment: Just so we can tailor our answer -- are you also confused about integer postfix operators? That is, do you understand `int i=0; i++; (i)++;`? And, do you understand the other aspects of pointer arithmetic? Do you understand `p+1` and `*(p+1) = 3`?

Comment: a) what exactly are you confused about? Do you understand the fully parenthesised expressions? b) Don't use pointers. They're hardly ever needed explicitly in C++, and never if you're just beginnig.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Iterators use the same syntax.  And there's nothing wrong with raw pointers used for iteration, it's only lifetime management that you want to avoid them.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm happy with iterators, but once raw pointers are at play and pointer arithmetic is asked for, there's loads of confusion about how much the pointer advances coming up just over the horizon. Next thing we have a question about void pointer arithmetic...

Comment: @KerrekSB: There's no such thing as void pointer arithmetic, you can't use arithmetic operations on any pointer to incomplete type, of which `void` is just one example.  And `std:vector<T>::iterator` might be a raw pointer.  Understanding that pointer arithmetic is measured in elements, not bytes, is fundamental to much of C++.

Comment: We all get confused by order of precedence.  Therefore, just use parenthesis whenever there's a doubt.

Comment: The only one to worry about is *p++ (the other two look easy to understand (Stuff in braces is done first)). But since *p++ depends on a set of rules nobody can remember and has to look up each time **avoid using it**.

Comment: @LokiAstari: except that it is idiomatic for out iterators: `while (it!=end) *out++ = *it++;`

Comment: @sehe: Yes we see that and you and I know what it means of the top of our heads. But my advice for most people is still not to do that. The case you point is a special case that people are taught to recognize, but in general `good engineers` don't write code that is so ...(compressed) That is left for the library engineers who have many thousands of people code reviewing their code. I would not call it idiomatic for out iterators I would call it a left over from the cold dark days of C and pointers.

Comment: @LokiAstari: In that case, I suppose you need to provide a better definition of 'we' :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*p++`

For this one, `++` has higher precedence then `*` so it increments the pointer by one but retrieves the value at the original location since post-increment returns the pointer and then increments its value.

`(*p)++`

This forces the precedence in the other direction, so the pointer is de-referenced first and then the value at that location in incremented by one (but the value at the original pointer location is returned).

`*(p++)`

This one increments the pointer first so it acts the same as the first one.

An important thing to note, is that the amount the pointer is incremented is affected by the pointer type.  From the link you provided:

```
char *mychar;
short *myshort;
long *mylong;
```

`char` is one byte in length so the `++` increases the pointer by 1 (since pointers point to the beginning of each byte).

`short` is two bytes in length so the `++` increases the pointer by 2 in order to point at the start of the next short rather than the start of the next byte.

`long` is four bytes in the length so the `++` increases the pointer by 4.

Comment: Ok, so (*p)++ affects what p is pointing at and *p++ affects the actual pointer's memory location.

Comment: This answer confuses preincrement and postincrement.

Comment: @VinylScratch: That's right, but `*p++` (equivalent to `*(p++)`) gets the value referred to by `p`, and adjusts the pointer afterward.

Comment: The first point made by this answer goes badly wrong.  While ++ does have higher precedence than *, the postfix ++ deliberately returns the value of the point prior to incrementing, so that *p++ retrieves the value at the unincremented location.  Please fix this.

Comment: short is NOT necessarily two bytes in length.  It is sizeof short bytes.  Similarly, long is sizeof long bytes.

Comment: On 64-bit Unix systems, long is often 8 bytes, not 4.  There is unwritten agreement that int is 4 bytes, but do not count on it without checking it.

Answer (score 1):

I found useful some years ago an explanation of strcpy, from Kernighan/Ritchie (I don't have the text available now, hope the code it's accurate): cpy_0, cpy_1, cpy_2 are all equivalent to strcpy:

```
char *cpy_0(char *t, const char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; t[i]; i++)
        t[i] = s[i];
    t[i] = s[i];
    i++;
    return t + i;
}
char *cpy_1(char *t, const char *s)
{
    for ( ; *s; ++s, ++t)
        *t = *s;
    *t = *s;
    ++t;
    return t;
}
char *cpy_2(char *t, const char *s)
{
    while (*t++ = *s++)
        ;
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*p++
```

Returns the content, **p*, an then increases the pointer's value (postincrement). For example:

```
int numbers[2];
int *p;
p = &numbers[0];
*p = 4;        //numbers[0] = 4;
*(p + 1) = 8;  //numbers[1] = 8;
int a = *p++;  //a = 4 (the increment takes place after the evaluation)
               //*++p would have returned 8 (a = 8)
int b = *p;    //b = 8 (p is now pointing to the next integer, not the initial one)
```

And about:

```
(*p)++
```

It increases the value of the content, **p = *p + 1;*.

```
(p++); //same as p++
```

Increases the pointer so it points to the next element (that may not exist) of the size defined when you declared the pointer.

Comment: "increases its value" is ambiguous here. It increments the pointer, not the pointee.

Comment: I allowed myself to restate that part a bit to make sure it's not confusing.

Comment: This is Undefined behavior: `*p = 4;`

Comment: @loki: that expression is not undefined behavior, that fact that its done on an uninitialized pointer is the UB

Comment: @Necrolis: In future I will be more pedantic about my explanations to make them screamingly obvious. not just obvious.

Comment: I just edited the answer, I hope it to be okay now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand what post increment does;
The post increment, increases the variable by one **BUT** the expression (p++) returns the original value of the variable to be used in the rest of the expression.

```
char   data[] = "AX12";
char* p;

p = data;
char* a = p++;

// a -> 'A'  (the original value of p was returned from p++ and assigned to a)
// p -> 'X'

p = data;   // reset;
char  l =  *(p++);

// l =  'A'. The (p++) increments the value of p. But returns the original
             value to be used in the remaining expression. Thus it is the
             original value that gets de-referenced by * so makeing l 'A'
// p -> 'X'
```

Now because of operator precedence:

```
*p++ is equivalent to *(p++)
```

Finally we have the complicated one:

```
p = data;
char m = (*p)++;

// m is 'A'. First we deference 'p' which gives us a reference to 'A'
//           Then we apply the post increment which applies to the value 'A' and makes it a 'B'
//           But we return the original value ('A') to be used in assignment to 'm'

// Note 1:   The increment was done on the original array
//           data[]  is now "BXYZ";
// Note 2:   Because it was the value that was post incremented p is unchaged.
// p -> 'B' (Not 'X')
```